# What is the best way to implement SSO-OBO flow for Outlook Mobile (IOS and Android)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have created an Outlook (GRAPH) addin that uses the SSO-OBO flow. It works perfectly with MAC-Outlook, Win-Outlook and Outlook Web Access.

However, when we opened the same addin in Outlook Mobile (IOS and Android), it kept on failing in the part where we were requesting for a token (Office.Auth.getAccessToken()). After some investigation, we found out that mobile Outlook does not support Identity API 1.3.

We would want our addin to work in Outlook Mobile using the SSO-OBO flow. Preferably, we would want to avoid popups or dialogs. But if that is inevitable then we go that way.

Here then are my questions :

1. What is the best way to implement the SSO-OBO flow (bootstrap-exchange-to-GRAPH token) for mobile Outlook addins?
2. Has anybody heard of a plan to support Identity API 1.3 for Mobile-Outlook? We have to consider that REST will be retired by November 2022.

I hope these questions made sense.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is up to you which solution to use. There is no such recommendations published.
2. Have never heard about such short-term plans. You can find Office versions and platforms that support 1.3 in the [Identity API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/identity-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview) article.

Note, you can file a new feature request or vote for the existing one at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Eugene. Would you know one or two ways to get a graph token on Outlook-addins for mobile? Thank you.

Comment: OfficeJS doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: I just want to confirm if this mean SSO-OBO flow for GRAPH is not possible in mobile-Outlook addins? Or can i use msal for this one instead? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can try using MSAL. See [Authorize to Microsoft Graph from an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph-without-sso).